# Let $X = C[a,b]$ be a vector space of continuous real functions on the interval $[a,b] \subset{R}$ and $\|x\| = \sup\{|x(t) : t \in [a,b] \}$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

Let $X = C[a,b]$ be a vector space of continuous real functions on the interval $[a,b] \subset{R}$ and $\|x\| = \sup\{|x(t) : t \in [a,b] \}$, $x\in X$, norm on $X$. Prove that with $(Ax)t = t^2x(a)$, $x\in X$, is defined a limited linear operator $A\in B(x)$ and find $\|A\|$.

- I know that $A\in L(x)$ is continous, and 
  $$\|A\|=\sup \left\{\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}\right\}$$ when $\|x\|\neq 0$, and  $$\|A\|=\sup \{\|Ax\|\}$$ when $\|x\|= 1$, but I still do not know how to prove this.

Can please anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The difference between writing $x\epsilon X$ and writing $x\in X$ is not just that $\text{“}{\epsilon}\text{''}$ looks different from $\text{“}\in\text{''}$, but also that the latter has spacing appropriate to a binary relation symbol.  I changed that in the question, and also changed $sup$ to $\sup$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

You must be talking about bounded linear operators, not limited. In normed vector spaces it holds that a linear operator is bounded if and only if it is continuous. This even is given as a definition sometimes. Now, if your definition of bounded linear operator is that it maps bounded sets to bounded sets then:

From your expression for $||A||$ you get that $||Ax||\leq||A||||x||$ for every $x\in X$. From this, if $B\subset X$ is a bounded set (i.e. $\sup_{x\in B} ||x||<\infty$) then
$$\sup_{x\in B}||Ax||\leq||A||\sup_{x\in B}||x||<\infty,$$
so $A(B)$ is bounded.

To find the norm of $A$ just write
$$||Ax||=\sup\{|t|:t\in[a,b]\}|x(a)|$$
and taking supremes in $||x||=1$ you get $||A||=\max(|a|,|b|)$.